# Android app installed (with wrong package name) as system app but not visible in system partition

Tags: root-access, rom

System app Google Calculator update fails, but that's not the funny thing.

#### History

I was on `crDroid 7.8 (Android 11)` with `Google Calculator` app installed in `system` through `FlameGApps`.

Then I got the crDroid 7.10 update which switched `FlameGApps` with its own built-in GApps. So I re-flashed `FlameGApps`.

#### The Funny Thing

The now installed `Google Calculator` (whose actual package name is com.google.android.calculator) on my app drawer has package name `com.android.calculator2` (which is the package name for the AOSP calculator app).

`EDIT:` When I try installing `com.google.android.calculator`, it says `App already installed` and update succeeds.

`EDIT:` But, Play Store shows app isn't installed, and the installation fails only through Play Store.

#### What I tried

I've used a combination of `find` and `grep` on the `Android terminal` (with `root`) to hunt down all files having the name `calculator`. there exists no such file (or directory), yet the app (with the wrong package name) is installed.

The apps directory should be located in the `/system` partition.

I'm sure `/system` was mounted (read-only but mounted).

I've used `SD Maid` to hunt down app corpses. Again, there were no corpses of the calculator app.

I do not understand what's going on.

Comment: What does `pm list packages -f | grep calculator` show?

Comment: ```package:/data/app/~~L3_R9d-u3Egb0Y-58H_dLA==/com.android.calculator2-SuxybzjlUcjzT1_sP4Z-Ag==/base.apk=com.android.calculator2```

Comment: So `com.google.android.calculator` doesn't seem to be installed. Try installing it using `adb install -r --user 0` and share the exact error message it throws.

Comment: It was a success, no error. Installing failed only thru play store.

Comment: As that seems to solve the issue: mind making it an answer, @IrfanLatif?

Comment: I still couldn't understand why the app had the wrong package name. I think it's a bug in Android.

Comment: @OogleGlu you can self answer the question for the benefit of future visitors.